# how to run shellscript with argument through java

Tags: java, shell, arguments, execute

i'm trying to execute shellscript with args program through java

```
   String[] cmd = { "bash", "-F", "/home/admin/Desktop/test_full_incremental.sh" };
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: What is wrong? some exceptions?

Comment: @AVolpe no exception its unable to take mysql dump

Comment: What is the observed result ? please detail a little more where you're stuck and what is not working as expected... (But I suspect it is the use of bash without a fully qualified path which is causing you troubles as the PATH env variable of your jre may not include it)

Comment: Why are you using `-F`?

Comment: -F argument for full backup

Comment: you need to change the order, try `String[] cmd = { "/bin/bash", "/home/admin/Desktop/test_full_incremental.sh",
    "-F" };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of the parameters, try this:

```
 String[] cmd = { "bash", "/home/admin/Desktop/test_full_incremental.sh", "-F" };
```